# Bloated Excel file

Tags: microsoft-excel, compression

Someone send me an Excel file that's 10MB, and thus causes us email problems. When .zip'ed it goes to under 1MB, so presumably there's something wrong with the Excel sheet but is there any way to reduce the excel file in size without zipping it?

I have a range of versions of Excel available to me by the way.

Comment: I'm confused. " When .zip'ed it..." with "... is there any way to compress this somehow?". It seems that you have answered your own question.

Comment: You're right, I could have been clearer sorry, I mean 'actually make the .xls file smaller' sorry - as opposed to just using winzip/7zip 'externally'

Comment: Aah...as far as I know there is no built in compression. I am prepared to be wrong however.

Comment: Is there really that much data in the workbook, or is this a case of the million empty rows problem?

Comment: @Excellll very much the latter I believe, it's not my excel sheet and its 'owner' is a bit clueless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there is space that can be 'reclaimed', there are several different things you can try:

1. Reset all the Used Ranges in each workbook. This can be done using a VBA method like this:

   ```
   Public Sub ResetAllLastCells()

   Dim wks As Worksheet
   Dim i As Long

   For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
       i = wks.UsedRange.Rows.Count
   Next wks

   End Sub
   ```
2. Remove any unwanted custom styles. I use a VBA method as below to remove all custom styles:

   ```
   Public Sub StyleKill()

   Dim s As Style

   For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Styles
       If Not s.BuiltIn Then
           s.Delete
       End If
   Next s

   End Sub
   ```
3. If there is VBA code within the workbook, try saving it decomiled. You can do this by opening the workbook, open the VBE, make a small change (add white space or something) and then, without compiling the project, save the workbook. This can dramatically reduce the file size.

I'm sure there are other ways too but these are my tried and tested ways. In one workbook I have this consistently reduces the file size from ~15mb to 10mb.

Comment: By the way, this did help a little - think we might have to do the whole 'transfer everything to a new file' thing I guess, cheers anyway.

Comment: I got error 1004 using *StyleKill* on the `s.Delete` line.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, the most common reason for this is blank lines that are within the used range within excel. Delete any blank rows below the range you have actually used (right click on the left and delete the whole rows, do not just clear contents), if that fails to reduce the size, use a macro like the following:

```
Sub DeleteBlankRows()

Cells.Select
Dim i As Long

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = Selection.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Selection.Rows(i)) = 0 Then
            Selection.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i

        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct, but use VB scripts. If you don't want to use scripts or if its just for a one off situation, you can also delete the unused space manually:

- Select any cell inside your content of your worksheet
- Hit `Ctrl`+`Home` on the keyboard to select the last used cell in the bottom right side
- Scroll back to your "real" last cell on the bottom right of your content
- Hold down `Shift` and click the cell below or right of it, depending on your unused layout
- Right-click inside the marked area and choose `Delete Rows` or `Delete Columns`, again depending on the layout

You may have to repeat those steps if you want to delete rows and columns simultaneously.